# Align table data by decimal points

Tags: tables

I have tried for about an hour and a half now to get my table data to align by the decimal places and I am beginning to lose my mind a bit.  I am aware of the `siunitx` and `dcolumn` packages but cannot get either to work for my table.  Could someone please help?  Thanks!  Below is the code for my table:

```
\begin{table}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{p{2.3cm}p{2.3cm}p{2.3cm}p{2.3cm}p{2.3cm}p{1.5cm}} \hline \hline
        Radius \newline ($R/R_\odot$) & Luminosity \newline ($L/L_\odot$) & Mass \newline ($M/M_\odot$) & Temperature \newline ($10^6$ K) & Density \newline (kg/m$^3$) & Pressure \newline ($P/P_c$) \\ \hline
        0.0 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 15.5   & 160000  & 1.00 \\
        0.1 & 0.42 & 0.07 & 13.0   & 90000    & 0.46 \\
        0.2 & 0.94 & 0.35 & 9.5     & 40000    & 0.15 \\
        0.3 & 0.99 & 0.64 & 6.7     & 13000    & 0.04 \\
        0.4 & 0.99 & 0.85 & 4.8     & 4000      & 0.007 \\
        0.5 & 0.99 & 0.94 & 3.4     & 1000      & 0.001 \\
        0.6 & 0.99 & 0.98 & 2.2     & 400        & 0.0003 \\
        0.7 & 0.99 & 0.99 & 1.2     & 80          & 4$\times10^{-5}$ \\
        0.8 & 0.99 & 1.00 & 0.7     & 20          & 5$\times10^{-6}$ \\
        0.9 & 0.99 & 1.00 & 0.3     & 2            & 3$\times10^{-7}$\\
        1.0 & 0.99 & 1.00 & 0.006 & 0.0003   & 4$\times10^{-13}$ \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table}
```

And here is what the current table looks like.  Note that the decimal points are not aligned (see Temperature column):
[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's easy with `siunitx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-0.3pt}
\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  S[table-format=1.1]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=2.3]
  S[table-format=6.4,group-digits=integer,group-four-digits]
  S[table-format=1.2e-2]
  @{}
}
\toprule
{Radius} & {Luminosity} & {Mass} & {Temperature} & {Density} & {Pressure} \\
{($R/R_\odot$)} & {($L/L_\odot$)} & {($M/M_\odot$)} &
  {(\SI[parse-numbers=false]{10^6}{K})} & {(\si{kg/m^3})} & {($P/P_c$)} \\
\midrule
0.0 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 15.5  & 160000  & 1.00   \\
0.1 & 0.42 & 0.07 & 13.0  &  90000  & 0.46   \\
0.2 & 0.94 & 0.35 & 9.5   &  40000  & 0.15   \\
0.3 & 0.99 & 0.64 & 6.7   &  13000  & 0.04   \\
0.4 & 0.99 & 0.85 & 4.8   &   4000  & 0.007  \\
0.5 & 0.99 & 0.94 & 3.4   &   1000  & 0.001  \\
0.6 & 0.99 & 0.98 & 2.2   &    400  & 0.0003 \\
0.7 & 0.99 & 0.99 & 1.2   &     80  & 4e-5   \\
0.8 & 0.99 & 1.00 & 0.7   &     20  & 5e-6   \\
0.9 & 0.99 & 1.00 & 0.3   &      2  & 3e-7   \\
1.0 & 0.99 & 1.00 & 0.006 & 0.0003  & 4e-13  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Tables with heterogeneous data are always difficult to typeset. If you don't want the space before the times sign in the last column, change the table preamble into

```
\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  S[table-format=1.1]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=2.3]
  S[table-format=6.4,group-digits=integer,group-four-digits]
  S[table-format=1.0e-2,table-align-exponent=false]
  @{}
}
```

and the output will be

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thank you!  I tried playing around with the package but couldn't get it to work myself.  One question: How do I remove the spaces between the digit and the multiplication sign in the values at the bottom of the last column?

Comment: @Spahn711 Good question! Change the last column specification into `S[table-format=1.0e-2,table-align-exponent=false]`

Comment: Works perfectly!  Thanks again, you're a life saver!

Comment: @egreg `S[table-format=1.0e-2]` should be enough.

Comment: @egreg a brief question: what does @{} do in tabular environment? I've never seen this before. Is it siunitx related?

Comment: @Leeser It removes the padding between (or before or after) columns.